# Detecting combination of characters from input

Tags: c

My task is:

Write a program that reads input up to # and reports the number of times that the sequence ei occurs.

I wrote something that in most of the times works, but there are inputs when it dosent...

Like this input:(suppose to return 1)

```
sdlksldksdlskd
sdlsklsdks
sldklsdkeisldksdlk
#
number of combination is: 0
```

This is the code:

```
int main(void)

{
    int index = 0;
    int combinationTimes = 0;
    int total = 0;
    char userInput;
    char wordChar[index];

    printf("please enter your input:\n");

    while ((userInput = getchar()) != '#')
    {
        if (userInput == '\n')
            continue;

        wordChar[index] = userInput;
        index++;
        total++;
    }

    for (index = 1; index < total; index++)
    {
        if (wordChar[index] == 'i')
        {
            if (wordChar[--index] == 'e')
            {
                combinationTimes++;
                ++index;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("number of combination is: %d", combinationTimes);

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please tell me what am I not getting 1 using this input?

in the book he said to test it with "Receive your eieio award" and it worked...but after i played with it a little i see that not always.

Comment: your `wordChar` array is currently being initialized with size `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't seem necessary to read the file into an array.  You just need to keep track of how many times `ei` is found before you read a `#` or reach EOF:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int ei_count = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '#')
    {
        if (c == 'e')
        {
            int c1 = getchar();
            if (c1 == 'i')
                ei_count++;
            else if (c1 != EOF)
                ungetc(c1, stdin);
        }
    }
    printf("ei appeared %d times\n", ei_count);
    return(0);
}
```

Testing (the program is called `ei` and is built from `ei.c`):

```
$ ei < ei.c
ei appeared 0 times
$ sed 1d ei.c | ei
ei appeared 1 times
$ sed 's/#/@/' ei.c | ei
ei appeared 4 times
$
```

The first one stops at the `#include` line, the second stops at the `#` in the comparison, and the third reads the entire file.  It also gives the correct output for the sample data.

---

#### Analysing the code

Your primary problem is that you do not allocate any space for the array.  Change the dimension of the array from `index` to, say, 4096.  That'll be big enough for your testing purposes (but really the program should pay attention to the array and not overflowing it — but then I don't think the array is necessary at all; see the code above).

The next primary problem is that despite its name, `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  It can return any valid character plus a distinct value, EOF.  So it must return a value that's bigger than a `char`.  (One of two things happens if you use `char`.  If `char` is a signed type, some valid character — often ÿ, y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS — is also treated as EOF even though it is just a character.  If `char` is an unsigned type, then no input matches EOF.  Neither is correct behaviour.)

Fixing that is easy, but your code does not detect EOF.  Always handle EOF; the data may be malformatted.  That's a simple fix in the code.

A tertiary problem is that the `printf()` statement does not end with a newline; it should.

Your test condition here is odd:

```
        if (wordChar[--index] == 'e')
        {
            combinationTimes++;
            ++index;
        }
```

It's odd to use one pre-increment and one post-increment, but that's just a consistency issue.
Worse, though, is what happens when the character `i` appears in the input and is not preceded by `e`.  Consider the line `@include <stdio.h>`: you start with `index` as 1; that is an `i`, so you decrement index, but `wordChar[0]` is not an `e`, so you don't increment it again, but the end of the loop does, so the loop checks `index` 1 again, and keeps on going around the loop testing that the `i` is `i` and `@` is not `e` for a long time.

There's no reason to decrement and then increment `index`; just use:

```
        if (wordChar[index-1] == 'e')
            combinationTimes++;
```

With those fixed, your code behaves.  You trouble was largely that you were using an array that was not big enough (being size 0), and you were overwriting quasi-random memory with the data you were reading.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int index = 0;
    int combinationTimes = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int userInput;
    char wordChar[4096];

    printf("please enter your input:\n");

    while ((userInput = getchar()) != '#' && userInput != EOF)
    {
        if (userInput == '\n')
            continue;

        wordChar[index] = userInput;
        index++;
        total++;
    }
    printf("total: %d\n", total);

    for (index = 1; index < total; index++)
    {
        if (wordChar[index] == 'i')
        {
            if (wordChar[index-1] == 'e')
                combinationTimes++;
        }
    }

    printf("number of combination is: %d\n", combinationTimes);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you could reasonably write the nested `if` as:

```
        if (wordChar[index] == 'i' && wordChar[index-1] == 'e')
            combinationTimes++;
```

Comment: Incidentally, you could micro-optimize my code by only pushing back the lookahead character if it is either '`#`' or `'e'`; anything else can stay read.  On the whole, you're unlikely to be able to measure the performance benefit of making that change.

Comment: Jonathan thank you so much for your answer, it helped me to understand allot of things im doing wrong. since im only learning C for the last 2 weeks and its my first programming language, this is extremely valuable lesson. thanks. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What does this do.  ungetc(c1, stdin);

Comment: @Sibrajas: [`ungetc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ungetc.html) pushes a character back onto the input stream.  Basically, it makes the given character available again for re-reading.  It is crucial that if the input sequence is `eei`, the `ei` is counted; if the second `e` was not pushed back, the count would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

change your `wordChar` array value.

```
int main(void)

{
    int index = 0;
    int combinationTimes = 0;
    int total = 0;
    char userInput;
    //char wordChar[index]; // index = 0
    char wordChar[255]; // should change the value of array.

    printf("please enter your input:\n");

    while ((userInput = getchar()) != '#')
    {
        if (userInput == '\n')
            continue;

        wordChar[index] = userInput;
        index++;
        total++;
    }

    for (index = 1; index < total; index++)
    {
        if (wordChar[index] == 'i')
        {
            if (wordChar[--index] == 'e')
            {
                combinationTimes++;
                ++index;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("number of combination is: %d", combinationTimes);

    return 0;
}
```

or maybe you can use `pointer` and then use `malloc` and `realloc`.